# .htaccess redirect subdomain dynamicly without changing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need to have a .htaccess redirect.
If I go to `example.bla.org`
I want it to redirect to `bla.org/example`
EXCEPT: It must keep the subdomain url can needs to be dynamic.
Ex: `example.bla.org/apple` -> `bla.org/example/apple`
I have tried almost every method like this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examples.website.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /examples/$1 [L]
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish here? Do you have access to the central server configuration? Much wiser to have `example.bla.org` point to `bla.org/example` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.website.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.org/example/$1 [L]
```

If you want to do a 301 redirect for SEO etc, add `R=301` to the rewrite :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.org/example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works, but the url does not stay at the example.website.org.So if I go to `example.website.org` it redirects to `website.org/example` in the url.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it is still redirecting in the url bar, I tried both of your ideas.

Comment: When you use  `http://` in the target address Apache will always do a header redirect, I think. You'd have to use a proper file path - but it'll only work if the path is underneath the virtual host's path. What the OP wants to do may not be possible without changing the central server config

Comment: @Pekka웃 How would I do it then?

Comment: @StratHaxxs as said above, the best way would be to have `example.website.org` point directly to the directory you want, instead of taking the detour

Comment: I see - I still didn't catch that OP was after an internal redirect.  @Pekka웃 you are right AFAIK - changing host names will always do an external redirect.  From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html : "If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL."

Comment: @Pekka웃 If you know how I could do what I asked please post an answer to help clarify and make sure I can set everything up right.

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now I'm afraid (I have to work)... but it really comes down to getting the subdomains' paths right from the start. Do you have access to Apache's central configuration on your server? The .conf files?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, I host the server myself and I have access to every file

Comment: @Strat Then you have the subdomain `example.bla.org` set up somewhere in there, correct?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, I have example.bal.org

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't own, bal.org, just a typo :)

Comment: @Strat And that subdomain points to a directory, correct? Just change that directory to where `bla.org/example` is.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Just to tell you, you do not need to @ Strat to me. But no, I could make a page rule in cloudflare..

Comment: If it's Apache, the subdomain points to *some* directory somewhere though. Not sure where Cloudflare comes in.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If I go the the subdomain it just goes to the regular homepage as if I typed in www.bla.org

Comment: Then you need to set up the subdomain properly http://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am using XAMPP on Windows not Ubuntu

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the help, I think I have solved my issue.